# Retorno Ajax com resultado múltiplo e criando linhas

Tags: jquery, ajax

Devido a uma necessidade interna, preciso fazer com que o retorno de uma consulta Ajax crie linhas para cada resultado exibido. Hoje tenho uma função que uso e que funciona normalmente quando o resultado é somente de uma linha, como abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, se o retorno é de mais de um resultado, recebo o erro abaixo, dentro da própria biblioteca Jquery:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim envio o JSON:

```
 while (OCIFetch($consulta2)){

     $array = array('codigo'=>$v_codigo, 'descricao'=>$v_descricao, 'status'=>$v_status, 'lote'=>$v_lote, 'endereco'=>$v_endereco, 'validade'=>$v_validade, 'qtde'=>$v_qtde);
     echo json_encode($array);

}
```

A função que "recebe" o JSON é essa:

```
   // Atribui uma função para ser executada sempre que houver uma mudança de estado
    xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // Verifica se foi concluído com sucesso e a conexão fechada (readyState=4)
        if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {
          // Verifica se o arquivo foi encontrado com sucesso
            if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
                //Se o retorno foi vazio do Oracle
                if (xmlreq.responseText == "") {
                    document.getElementById("codigo").focus();
                   ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = '';
                    });
                //Se encontrou dados
                } else {
                    //Aqui recebe os dados do processa.php, abre e aplica nos campos desejados
                    var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
                    // função para preencher os campos com os dados
                    ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = dados[id];
                    });
                }
            } else {
                result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
            }
        }
        requestActive = false;
    };
    xmlreq.send(null);
```

É essa mesma função que estou tentando alterar para criar as linhas da tabela automaticamente quando encontrar mais de um resultado. Segui [esse exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242536/generate-table-row-dynamically-on-ajax-success), coloquei id na table no html, mas não consegui alterar esse ajax que uso. 
Alguma sugestão?

**UPDATE**

Com a resposta do @Guerra, o JSON passou para o Ajax, e com o código abaixo criou as linhas que precisava:

```
   var HTML = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' style='width:500px'>";

                        HTML += "<tr><th>Status</th><th>Lote</th><th>Endereco</th><th>Validade</th><th>Qtde</th></tr>";

                        var data = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
                        document.getElementById("descricao").value = data[0].descricao; //POSIÇÃO 0 PARA SEMPRE PEGAR O PRIMEIRO NOME DO ARRAY
                        for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
                          HTML += "<tr><td><input type = 'text' value=" + data[i].status + "></td>";
                          HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' value=" + data[i].lote + "></td>";
                          HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' value=" + data[i].endereco + "></td>";
                          HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' value=" + data[i].validade + "></td>";
                          HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' value=" + data[i].qtde + "></td></tr>";
                        }

                        HTML += "<tr><td colspan='7'><center><input type = 'button' value = 'Limpar' class='btn'";
                        HTML += "onclick='location.href='ConfirmaTransferencia.php''>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
                        HTML += "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Gravar' class='btn'></center></td></tr>";
                        HTML += "</table>";

                        document.getElementById('locais').innerHTML = HTML;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está montando o JSON errado.
Você não está retornando um Json com varias linhas e sim varios com uma linha.

O certo seria monta-lo dessa forma:

```
while (OCIFetch($consulta2)){

     $array[] = array('codigo'=>$v_codigo, 'descricao'=>$v_descricao, 'status'=>$v_status, 'lote'=>$v_lote, 'endereco'=>$v_endereco, 'validade'=>$v_validade, 'qtde'=>$v_qtde);

}
     echo json_encode($array);
```

O Json que retorna deveria ser algo assim:

```
[
   {"codigo":"12312",...},
   {"codigo":"12312",...}
]
```

Comment: Show, essa parte deu certo. Agora estou com problema na segunda parte, no Ajax mesmo. Como trato ele no recebimento? Lá ele diz que o "dados[i]" não existe....

Comment: veja o update da minha questão....obrigado!